# jprofiler. how to export results on linux

Tags: jprofiler

I run command `sh jpexport /opt/jprofiler8/Snapshots/test/test.0.jps AllObjects -format=html /opt/jprofiler8/Snapshots/test/test.0.html`
And get next log.

`[was@test-env3 bin]$ sh jpexport /opt/jprofiler8/Snapshots/test/test.0.jps AllOb                 jects -format=html /opt/jprofiler8/Snapshots/test/test.0.html
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was                  removed in 8.0
Loading /opt/jprofiler8/Snapshots/test/test.0.jps
JProfiler has not been initialized. Please run the JProfiler executable first`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The export executables in JProfiler only work if the license key has been set. Run the JProfiler GUI first to enter your key. If you don't have a UI on the machine, copy `$HOME/.jprofiler10/config.xml` from another computer where the key has been entered to the same location.

Comment: Thnx. I add it to $HOME/.jprofiler10/config.xml Than tried to run jpanalyze, it works. but jpexport still got the same error

Comment: jpanalyze does not need the license key but jpexport does. Is there a license key in config.xml?